# Is there a infinite content scroll that will scroll horizontally?

Tags: javascript, scroll, pagination

Is there an infinite content scrolling code that will scroll horizontally? It's also known as autopagerize, unpaginate, endless pages, endless scrolling, infinite pagination etc. It seems to be very popular on tumblr the blogging website and a lot of online news sources. However wasn't able to find one that will scroll horizontally. [Example](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/)

Also is there a version that is similar to the tumblr one that doesn't tell you it's loading the next page?

Answer (score 0):

The code would be exactly the same.

Just adjust your css so that the items are *displayed* horizontally instead of vertically.